# What is git worktree identifier

Tags: git, git-worktree

When a new git worktree is created, it shows a message like below

```
$ git worktree add -b hotfix ../hotfix origin/master
Enter ../hotfix (identifier hotfix)
Branch hotfix set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'hotfix'
$ cd ../hotfix
```

Here, what is the use of identifier? I have observed that if I create another worktree on a different path but same folder name like `../abc/hotfix`, it will assign the identifier as `hotfix2`. Is there any usage of this identifier for the user like using the identifier to move to particular worktree or delete it specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "identifier" printed here is just the last part of an internal name (`sb_repo.buf`).  It has no actual significance to normal users in normal cases, but it's the unique name of the subdirectory within `.git/worktrees` containing the administrative files for the specified work-tree.  **If you manually rename the work-tree (changing its path)**, you must update one of these administrative files.  This is described in the [DETAILS section of the `git worktree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html#_details).

While this identifier is printed at the time the work-tree is created, it's most likely that if you *do* move an added work-tree, you would do that long after adding it, and have forgotten the identifier, so in my opinion, the message itself is useless now (i.e., it was probably useful to the developer during development but is now just leftover junk).  The path to the administrative files is directly in the `.git` file in the added work-tree:

```
$ cat .git
gitdir: [...]/git/.git/worktrees/hotfix
```

and since that's what you need to know, you would find it by looking at `.git`.

Note that the message was changed from `Enter %s (identifier %s)` to `Preparing %s (identifier %s)` in Git version 2.6.0, via [commit cd2f471311](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd2f4713112119e18af8b5b580c5661a52320632), so this means you are running Git 2.5.x, which has some small bugs with added work-trees (not huge ones, but I'd recommend moving to a later Git version).